# Setting the SVN "execute" bit in a Subversion repository using TortoiseSVN or command line SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I've got an open-source app that is hosted at code.google.com. It is cross platform ( Linux / Windows / Mac ). I uploaded the code initially from a WinXP machine using TortoiseSVN and it seems that none of the "configure" batch files that are used for the linux build have their "execute" bits set.

What would be the easiest way to set these for the files that need them? Using TortoiseSVN would be easier, I suppose, but if that can't be used, then I could also use the command line SVN on my linux machine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With tortoise SVN, it's quite easy: you can select several files (may be from search results, so they don't have to be in the same directory), select "properties" in the TortoiseSVN menu, add the needed property (there is a drop-down list of the mostly used properties, in this case "svn:executable") and set the value (in this case "*"). If committing the changed files and checking them out under linux, the executable bit will be set.

If you want to set more than one property at once, it may be more secure (in case of mistakes) to first set the properties correctly for one file, export them into a file, select all needed files, select the "properties" menu and import the previously saved properties.

Answer (score 83):

Here's how to do it on the command line:

```
for file in `find . -name configure`; do
  svn ps svn:executable yes ${file}
done
```

Or for just one file (`configure` is the filename here):

```
svn ps svn:executable yes configure
```

Comment: You can also use propset on a list of files -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5757365/134647

Comment: Note that to clear the executable bit you have to use svn propdel svn:executable <foo>.  You can't just set it to "no".

Answer (score 7):

On Unix use {} to adress resulset:

```
find . -type f -name "*.bat" -exec svn propset svn:executable yes '{}' \;
```

Does anyone know why this property requires "yes" as valid argument? 
Found another example with '' instead of yes, works too...

Comment: THe svn:executable property is a boolean value.  Setting it to "yes" or "*" or _anything_ is sufficient.   svn checks if the property is set, not its content - most clients with report the value as '*' even if you set it to 'yes'.

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -type f -name "*.bat" -exec svn propset svn:executable yes "${}" \;
```

Of course the same goes for .exe, etc.

Comment: This is Windows version? Just wondering, that [erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624864/384674), which is younger has more votes, seems pretty same to me...

Answer (score 1):

Method for restoring executable permissions that are lost during svn import:

copy permissions from your original source that you used during svn import (current dir to version1):

```
find . -type f | xargs -I {} chmod --reference {} ../version1/{}
```

then set svn:executable for all executables using the following shell script:

```
for file in `find . -executable -type f`; do
  svn ps svn:executable yes ${file}
done
```